# Storybook 7 pass props between component

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm looking for a solution for my story. I've trying to pass some props from a mock component to a story.

Some props can be define outside the component but register and error should be pass by the MockForm.

edit 25/05 I tried this new version but all the props I put in my story are not sent.

```
<input type="text" class="form_atom_default_form_atoms__ghWWl p-3 text-base" aria-invalid="false">
```

I don't have the name the id ...

```js
type FormData = { itemName: string };

const meta: Meta<typeof FormInput<FormData>> = {
  title: "composite/form/molecules/form-input",
  component: FormInput,
};

export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>;

export const preview: Preview = {
  decorators: [(Story) => <MockForm Story={Story}></MockForm>],
};

function MockForm({ Story }: { Story: any }) {
  const validationFormSchema: ZodType<FormData> = z.object({
    itemName: z.string().min(2).max(30),
  });

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FormData>({
    resolver: zodResolver(validationFormSchema),
  });
  return (
    <form action="">
      <Story
        id="inputTest"
        register={register}
        rules={{ required: "You must enter your first name." }}
        errors={errors}
        name="itemName"
        labelText="testLabel"
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Instead of instantiating the Story in the Preview line, what if you just pass in its definition and instantiate it in the MockForm? Then you can add props to it.